# how to GROUP BY so that not all results are grouped

Tags: mysql, group-by, case

When I use my query to select all data from the table I have a problem with the custnumber field. If custnumber is returned within the same month then it should group the results but only then.

This is my query:

```
SELECT MONTH(periode) AS maand,
       YEAR(periode) AS jaar,            
       maandfacturen.verzenddatum,
       maandfacturen.factuurnr,
       maandfacturen.custnumber,
       klantgegevens.bedrijfsnaam AS bedrijfsnaam,
       maandfacturen.totaalbedragexcl,
       maandfacturen.totaalbedragincl,
       maandfacturen.betaald
FROM maandfacturen
LEFT JOIN klantgegevens ON maandfacturen.custnumber = klantgegevens.custnumber 
WHERE `periode` LIKE '2023%'  
GROUP BY custnumber
ORDER BY periode ASC, factuurnr ASC
```

This query does not work cause if I use GROUP BY custnumber it groups all records and thats not the result I need as all months also get grouped. After googling I found that I might need to use CASE to solve this but I am not sure how to use this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) #5 and #3 and edit the question. By the way you should enable sql_mode only_full_group_by and re-run your query

Comment: Is it possible for there to be the same `custnumber` within the same month but have different data between the rows in the other fields, such as `maandfacturen.factuurnr` or `maandfacturen.betaald`?

Comment: @J.D. not it is the same data. So the same custnumber always has the exact same data for maandfacturen.factuurnr or maandfacturen.betaald or any other field.

Answer (score 0):

> So the same custnumber always has the exact same data for maandfacturen.factuurnr or maandfacturen.betaald or **any** other field.

Ok, so if all of the fields you're selecting are always the same values (except the months and years obviously) for the same `custnumber` then just add all of those fields to your `GROUP BY` clause as well:

```
SELECT MONTH(periode) AS maand,
       YEAR(periode) AS jaar,            
       maandfacturen.verzenddatum,
       maandfacturen.factuurnr,
       maandfacturen.custnumber,
       klantgegevens.bedrijfsnaam AS bedrijfsnaam,
       maandfacturen.totaalbedragexcl,
       maandfacturen.totaalbedragincl,
       maandfacturen.betaald
FROM maandfacturen
LEFT JOIN klantgegevens ON maandfacturen.custnumber = klantgegevens.custnumber 
WHERE `periode` LIKE '2023%'  
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(periode),
    YEAR(periode),            
    maandfacturen.verzenddatum,
    maandfacturen.factuurnr,
    maandfacturen.custnumber,
    klantgegevens.bedrijfsnaam,
    maandfacturen.totaalbedragexcl,
    maandfacturen.totaalbedragincl,
    maandfacturen.betaald
ORDER BY periode ASC, factuurnr ASC
```

This allows you to `SELECT` those columns without having to aggregate them.